# Joomla 3.1: how to get timezone offset?

Tags: joomla, timezone-offset

Does anybody know how to get the system timezone offset in Joomla 3.1? I've tried the following:

```
    return JFactory::getConfig()->getValue('offset');
```

but this results in the following error:

```
    Fatal error: Call to undefined method JRegistry::getValue()
```

Thanks for any info pointing me in the right direction ....

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$offset = $config->get('offset');
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but this returns (for example) "Africa/Abidjan" ... however I am looking for the numeric value. Any ideas?

Comment: You could probably use the DateTimeZone::getOffset() method to get this:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone(JFactory::getConfig()->get('offset'));
$offset   = $timezone->getOffset(new DateTime)/3600;
```